# Gendarme integration with visual studio 2010 premium

Tags: mono, gendarme

I am new to using Gendarme. I downloaded this version of the tool (**Gendarme 2.11 (unsupported build - Win32 - Requires .NET Framework 4.0)**) from https://github.com/spouliot/gendarme/downloads and it worked fine as an independent app. But I want to integrate it with my VS2010 Premium. After lot of search I found that this (https://github.com/unintelligible/GendarmeMsBuild) is the only wrapper that serves my purpose. I did what has been mentioned there to integrate it with VS but I did not see any code review suggestion from the tool i.e. no output from the tool. I tried to integrate it only to VS and did not try for MSBuild yet.

What is it that I might be doing wrong? Anyone please?

I am also open to the idea of integrating Gendarme to VS and MSBuild by some other way too if it works.

Thanks in advance!